# How can I allow for string values in loop? Python

Tags: python

```
while age > 2018:
    print ("If that were true, you would not exist")
    age = eval(input("In what year were you actually born?"))
while age <= 1999:
    print ("if that were true you would have graduated")
    age = eval(input("In what year were you actually born?"))
while age == str():
    print ("Sorry I didn't understand that, make sure you only use integers in your year of birth")
    age = eval(input("in what year were you born?"))


num = int(input("what is your favourite number?"))
name = str(input("What is your name?"))
the_sum(age, num, name)
```

sentence()

How can I get this to accept a str as a response to any one of the questions and restate the question rather than report an error?

Comment: **DON'T USE EVAL D: D: D:** this allows people to break your program however they want. Use `int` to parse to an integer. Please. Thank you.

Comment: Python 2? Huh. Then this would create many issues. `int(input())` would be very un-user-friendly because then they'd have to enclose a number in quotes which is just terribly awkward.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino You should use `int(raw_input())` in Python 2. Just *don't use `eval` on user input!!!*, which Python 2 `input` does *implicitly*. There's a reason it was removed in Python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know that `input` is not recommended because code injection, but yeah `raw_input`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# keep going until a valid year is entered
while True:

    # keep prompting until a number is entered
    while True:
        year = input("In what year were you born? ")
        if year.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            print("That is not a number.  Please try again.")

    # we broke out of the input loop, so it's a number.  convert to integer
    year = int(year)

    if year > 2018:
        print ("If that were true, you would not exist")

    elif year <= 1999:
        print ("if that were true you would have graduated")

    else:
        # success!  break out of the outer loop
        break
```

Comment: You don't need to nest the loop. Just chain the `if...else`.

Comment: Strings have a `.isdigit()` method, yes.

Comment: Not if you `continue` the loop if it's not an integer value.

Comment: Nest your loops, or nest the ifs.  There are advantages each way, I suppose.

Comment: The thing is the `if`s wouldn't be nested, they'd just be stacked. See my answer for example; it's just chained `if`s and not nested. (Unless `elif` is just nested `else: if: `...)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. One is that `age` is never initialized - you need to ask for it at the start. Another is that in Python 2, `input` will run whatever is input and evaluate to whatever that evaluates. What you actually want to do is probably take in the string that is the input, which you can do with `raw_input` in Python 2, or `input` in Python 3. `eval(input())` will try to evaluate whatever `input` returns, which is an integer if you put in a number, but `eval` wants to take in a string. Finally, you never define `the_sum`, but I'll assume you have it defined somewhere else and just haven't given it to us.

This gives us

```
age = int(raw_input("In what year were you born?"))
while age > 2018:
    print ("If that were true, you would not exist")
    age = int(raw_input("In what year were you actually born?"))
while age <= 1999:
    print ("if that were true you would have graduated")
    age = int(raw_input("In what year were you actually born?"))
while age == str():
    print ("Sorry I didn't understand that, make sure you only use integers in your year of birth")
    age = int(raw_input("in what year were you born?"))

num = int(raw_input("what is your favourite number?"))
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
the_sum(age, num, name)
```

If you're using Python 3, replace all `raw_input` with `input` in the code block above.

Comment: He's using `print()` instead of `print`, so I assume he's using python 3, therefore `input()` is the right function to use.

Comment: You might be right! Though I was taught to use parentheses with Python 2, even seven years ago. I'll edit my answer to account for this.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon the semantics won't be the same in Python 2 and Python 3, unless in Python 2 you do `from __future__ import print_function` or whatever it is. I haven't used Python 2 in *ages*

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loops appear to have no effect, and will cause errors as `age` is not defined. Instead, wrap the whole thing in a loop such that you keep taking input until the user actually inputs something correct.

```
year = None # If you don't preinitialize the variable name, then it will only exist in the local scope of the loop
while True:
    year = input("Please enter your year >>> ")
    if not year.isdigit():
        print("The entered value is not a valid integer.")
        continue # keep taking input
    year = int(year())
    if year >= 2018:
        print("That is in the future. Try again.")
    elif year <= 1999:
        print("You would have graduated by now (unless you keep failing school). Try again.")
    else: break # the value was correct :D
```

Instead of the `try... except` statement, you can do `if year and any(digit not in "0123456789" for digit in year)`, and that `if` statement is executed if the input is empty or not a number.